# Side-by-side pie charts of 2 matrices R

Tags: r, matrix, pie-chart

say you have 2 matrices `m1` and `m2` and each has equal an number of columns.

```
m1 = matrix(0, 10, 5, dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
m1[1,] = c(0,0,0,0,1)
m1[2,] = c(0,0,0,1,1)
m1[3,] = c(0,0,1,1,1)
m1[4,] = c(0,0,1,1,0)
m1[5,] = c(1,0,0,0,0)
m1[6,] = c(1,1,1,0,0)
m1[7,] = c(0,1,1,0,0)
m1[8,] = c(0,1,1,0,0)
m1[9,] = c(0,1,1,1,0)
m1[10,] = c(1,1,1,0,1)

m2 = matrix(0, 10, 5, dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
m2[1,] = c(0,0,0,0,1)
m2[2,] = c(0,0,0,1,1)
m2[3,] = c(0,0,1,1,1)
m2[4,] = c(0,0,1,1,0)
m2[5,] = c(1,0,0,0,0)
m2[6,] = c(1,1,1,0,0)
m2[7,] = c(0,1,1,0,0)
m2[8,] = c(0,1,1,0,0)
m2[9,] = c(0,1,1,1,0)
m2[10,] = c(1,1,1,0,1)
```

What I would like to see is a pie-chart comparison of these two matrices.

One way I can think is for each column, add each row, and then use those to get fractions for a pie chart.

```
sumcols <-function(x){
    for (i in 1:numcols(x)){
        sum <- sum(x[,i])
        sums.append(sum) #python here ...
    }
    return(sums)
}
```

so now, i can pass any matrix, get back a list of sums, which I assume now we can use to get a pie chart:

```
sums1 <- sumcols(m1)
sums2 <- sumcols(m2)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
pie(c(sums1,sums2))
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: (like zx8754 suggested)  No true Scientist will use pie charts.  Please consider using a more informative method, such as bar charts.

Comment: That is not true, pie charts have many uses, and one use, the one I want it for, we can see proportions of features comparing two sample sets.

Comment: Pie charts have many uses, all of them bad.  I strongly suggest you read some of  Ed Tufte's books on graphics.  There is nothing a pie chart can do that a bar chart or stacked bar chart can't do far better. To quote from the RCA Engineer, V3nbr3, 1985, "Pie chart[s] have the sole advantage of indicating that the data must add up to 100% of the total."

Comment: I actually have read that and other papers, and yes I agree not the best figure, but it has its uses. Specifically, I think it has a normalization effect, which I wont get in to the math, but one can look at proportions in a normalized way (i.e, is my slice of the cake bigger than mr x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you pie for 1st columns sums:

`pie(c(colSums(m1)[1],colSums(m2)[1]))`

I think barplot would be more informative:

`barplot(c(colSums(m1),colSums(m2)), col=c(rep(1,ncol(m1)),rep(2,ncol(m1))))`

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
#get col sums
m1_sums <- colSums(m1)
m2_sums <- colSums(m2)
#make negatives zero
m1_sums[m1_sums<0] <- 0
m2_sums[m2_sums<0] <- 0
#pie
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
pie(m1_sums,main="m1 - colSums")
pie(m2_sums,main="m2 - colSums")
```

[image]

Comment: This does make a pie chart, but not what I want. This gives me 1 pie chart comparing column 1 of m1 and m2. I want 2 pie charts. one representing m1, the other for m2.

Comment: What I need to do which i don't have the R chops, given matrix m1 and m2 (their column names are identical). So get column name, sum each column of each matrix to sum1 and sum2; pie chart these 2 matrices.

Comment: This works, but some columns sum to a negative (in my real example) and it errors "Error in pie(colSums(m1), main = "m1 - colSums") : 
  'x' values must be positive." So is there an easy to set those to 0 without passing to a variable and doing the change? in 1 step, adding to your current code?

Comment: @StudentOfScience updated the answer to assign zeros to negative numbers.